# Data Binding at wrong time in Jstree

Tags: json, ajax, jstree

Using jstree v3 I have

```
this.elements.$tree.jstree({
            core: {
                data: function (node, successCallback) {
                    // Handle node expansion
                    thisTmp._expandNode(node, successCallback);
                },
...
```

This works fine the first time I open a node and goes to my server and gets the child nodes. If I then close the node it is also called and I'd like to not bother the server at that point. Additionally if I then re-open the node this function is not called at all.

Investigating I noticed that the node passed always has a state of `loading: true` with all others set false.

Further investigation shows that this function is called before the `before_open.jstree` event, and after the `after_close.jstree` event. This probably explains the node state but doesn't help me.

I need it to call the webserver every time I open the node because the items represented by the child nodes may have changed since the last time you looked. That is there may be more/different/fewer nodes.

Spent all morning on this and can't see what I'm doing wrong (or should do differently). Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've found a solution...

In the after_close event I set the node's loaded state to false. This causes jstree to trigger the loading again when I next open the node and I get any updated tree items.